# can't fadeout a dynamic div using jquery

Tags: jquery, dynamic

I have following html structure in firstpage.php:

```
<div id="result" style="display:none">This is result div</div>
<form id="adres" onsubmit="return submitForm();">
<input type="hidden" name="type" value="some_value" />
<input type="submit" value="Open" />
</form>
```

And in inline-style:

```
#result{
position: absolute;
border: 5px solid gray;
padding: 10px;
background: white;
width: 270px;
height: 190px;
}
```

What this html page do, clicking on "Open" button of "adres" form, some post data is send to another php page which shows information based on sent data on a pop-up like div (which style was display:none) fadeIn from display:none. The javascript/jquery codes for this purpose are as follows:

```
function submitForm(){
  var data=$("#adres").serialize();
  $.post("anotherpage.php",data,
  function(data){
    $("#result").html(data);
    positionPopup();
    $("#result").fadeIn(1000);

  }
 )
return false;
}
function positionPopup(){
$("#result").css({
left: ($(window).width() - $('#result').width()) / 2,
top: ($(window).width() - $('#result').width()) / 2,
position:'absolute'
});
}

$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#divclose").click(function(){
    $(#result).fadeOut(500);
    return false;
});
});
```

and in anotherpage.php:

```
<?php
echo $_POST['type'];
?>
<br /><a href="#" id="divclose">Close</a>
```

i.e the div in firstpage.php with fetched data will pop-up like following structure:

```
<div id="result">
some_value
<a href="#" id="divclose">Close</a>
</div>
```

All things is going on okay upto this stage. But when I am clicking on "Close" link on pop-up div the div is not closing(fadeOut) with $("#divclose").click(function()
Why this is not happening in this case?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use function `on()` to bind events on dynamically created element :

http://api.jquery.com/on/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("body").on('click',"#divclose",function(){
        $('#result').fadeOut(500);
        return false;
    });
});
```

You have also a typo on line : `$(#result).fadeOut(500);` => `$('#result').fadeOut(500);`

Comment: This is not working/closing the div also. And you have also a typo in your code: .on('click',"#divclose",(function() => .on('click',"#divclose",function()

Comment: Have you checked the console (F12) to be sure that you have no error? You could also add a breakpoint in the click event callback to be sure that the code is called and check that you have only one div with ID "result"

Comment: Yes, I just have checked now and there is no another div with id result.

Comment: And If I put <a href="#" id="divclose">Close</a> itself in <div id="divclose"> then onclick div is closing accurately with my previous(first) code